# Citing photographs shared through social media in thesis

Tags: thesis, graphics

I have included two photographs related to my research in my thesis. The photographs were shared with me by my connections on Facebook as private messages. How can I state the source of the photographs in the thesis? My idea is:

Figure 1. Caption. Photograph taken by NAME, reused with permission.

(I requested my connections over Facebook message if I may use the photographs they sent, and they had no issues.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that’s fine. Get written permission, though. Some such things are marked as “private communication.”

Save the permission. Don't depend on FB to do it for you. Cache it, or get an email with permission, perhaps.